# How to use bool? in if statement?

Tags: c#, nullable

I want to use a nullable boolean in an if statement. But I get the following compiler error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) csharp(CS0266)`

How can I easily cast `bool?` to `bool`?

This is sample code that throws the error:

```cs
bool? nullable = null;
if(nullable) return;
```

Comment: I created this duplicate question on purpose, because it wasn't straightforward to find the duplicates quickly through Google. Also, the answers to the duplicates weren't straightforward either.

Answer (score 1):

For C# 8.0 upwards, the quickest way is to use the binary null-coalescing operator `??` which returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result as follows:

```cs
bool? nullable = null;
if(nullable ?? false) return; //if nullable is null, default to false
```

Depending on what you want to happen if `nullable` is `null` you put `false` or `true` on the right hand side of `??`.

See documentation for `??` on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Another option is to use `nullable.GetValueOrDefault()` which does not allow one to return `true` in case of `null` however (thanks user:Magnus)

To work around this caveat, you can first handle the case if nullable is false, then use `.GetValueOrDefeault()` knowing that the default will never be used:

```
if(nullable == null ? false : nullable.GetValueOrDefault()) return;
```

Comment: Or if you are using an older version of C#, use the explicit cast: `if ((bool)nullable)`

Comment: What's the result of this explicit cast? Is it the default value `null`?

Comment: Another option  `if (nullable.GetValueOrDefault()) return`

Comment: @Jay Buckman That wont work. Will throw `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: The null coalescing operator was introduced in C# 2, not 8...

Comment: @Magnus I agree.  I've used it in cases where I know the value isn't null, but `GetValueOrDefault()` is obviously a better solution.