# How can I use the null-conditional operator to safely and briefly check a nullable reference type's property

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable

Given code like:

`Thing? maybeAThing = GetThing();`

I want to write logic that safely checks if the object is not null and has a certain property:

`if(maybeAThing is not null && maybeAThing.IsAGoodThing){ ... }`

But this syntax seems a bit messy. I thought the null-conditional operators were supposed to let me do this as any test will fail as soon as null is encountered:

`if(maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing){...}`

But this gives compiler error:

> CS0266 cannot implicitly convert bool ? to bool

It seems the 'nullableness' is extending to the return value (`bool?`) instead of the test failing as soon as `maybeAThing` is determined to be `null`.

Is this specific to NRTs rather than nullable value types? Is there a way to do this without having to write additional clauses, and if not then what is my misunderstanding in the way the language works?

Comment: I think you would get away with `if (maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing == true) { ... }`

Comment: [How to use bool? in if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702823/how-to-use-bool-in-if-statement) or many similar questions on topic: "CS0266 bool"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write some variant of:

```
maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing == true
maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing ?? false
(maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing).GetValueOfDefault(false)
```

You can also use a property pattern:

```
maybeAThing is { IsAGoodThing: true }
```

Comment: Maybe the `GetValueOfDefault` way needs a parenthesis: `(maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing).GetValueOfDefault(false)`

Comment: I've not really come across property patterns. I'll accept this asnwer for giving more options

Answer (score 2):

You can just write:

```
if(maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing == true){...}


null == true  //Nope
false == true //Nope
true == true  //Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if(maybeAThing?.IsAGoodThing == true){...}
```

This converts the `Nullable<bool>` to a `bool`.

[Lifted Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators)

> For the equality operator ==, if both operands are null, the result is
> true, if only one of the operands is null, the result is false;
> otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared.